# How to insert XML File NodeValue to SQL server database?

Tags: java, sql-server, xml, database, insert

I am trying to insert XML file to SQL server database, but still don't know what's wrong with my code below.

My XML node names are: author, title, genre, price, publish_date, description.

By getting the above node names I want to create columns in my database table so that I can insert the node values into the columns.

My XML File Looks Like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Results>
<Row>
  <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
  <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
  <genre>Computer</genre>
  <price>44.95</price>
  <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
  <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
  with XML.</description>
</Row>

<Row>
  <author>Corets, Eva</author>
  <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
  <genre>Fantasy</genre>
  <price>5.95</price>
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .    
  </Row>
  </Results>
```

Java Code to insert into  database:

```
try{
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();

    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                              "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;user=joy\studentsdatabaseName=EMPLOYEEintegratedSecurity=t    rue;");

    Statement st=con.createStatement();

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

    Document doc = db.parse("d:/books.xml");

    NodeList n1= doc.getElementsByTagName("Row");
    for(int i=0;i<n1.getLength();i++){
        String st1= n1.item(i).getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

        System.out.println(st1);    // i dont know why it doesnt print anything ?

        st.executeUpdate("insert into checktbl(sub)values('"+st1+"')");

    }
}
catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because there's a whitespace child text node before author, after Row element. Eg: following XML doesn't have whitespace between Row and author:

```
<Row><author>blah</author></Row>
```

But following might have (yes the spaces and linebreaks often counts!)

```
<Row>
   <author>blah</author></Row>
```

But this can depend on parser configuration too

Comment: oh yes gerrytan i did the change you said, but it now prints null